# How to change UISearchBar Icon to custom image?

Tags: ios, swift, icons, customization, uisearchbar

Currently, I have the default magnifying glass as my search bar icon. However, I want to put a custom image in its place, particularly this image:

**Custom Arrow Icon**

[image: Screen Shot]

How would I go about changing the search bar default icon to the custom image?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you can use `setImage` function

```
 searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "your image"), forSearchBarIcon: .Search, state: .Normal)
```

**Swift3**

```
searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "Image Name"), for: .search, state: .normal)
```

Answer (score 18):

**Way 1 :**

As **luiyezheng** answer, You can change the image of UISearchBar iCon.

```
UISearchBar.appearance().setImage(UIImage(named: "new_search_icon"), forSearchBarIcon: UISearchBarIcon.Search, state: UIControlState.Normal)
```

**Search Icon image Change**

[image: screen shot]

**Way 2 :**

you can change tint color of Search iCon of `UISearchBar` iCon.

```
let textFieldInsideSearchBar = searchBarCustom.valueForKey("searchField") as? UITextField
let imageV = textFieldInsideSearchBar?.leftView as! UIImageView
imageV.image = imageV.image?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
imageV.tintColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
```

**Output :**

Search Icon image tint color change

[image: screen shot]

Comment: With Swift 4.2: `imageV.image = imageV.image?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)`

Answer (score 2):

**luiyezheng**'s answer works great.
The Swift 3 version of it is:

```
searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "Image Name"), for: .search, state: .normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**, **iOS 13+**

This is pretty easy, starting from iOS 13 `UISearchBar` has a `.searchTextField` property we may want to tweak somehow.

Just set image view as its `.leftView` property, apply required tint color if needed.

```swift
let image = UIImage(systemName: "location")
searchBar.searchTextField.leftView = UIImageView(image: image)
searchBar.searchTextField.leftView?.tintColor = .purple
```