# Swift : Add image to scopebar in uiSearchbar instead of titles

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

I am trying to set an image to scope bar in uisearch bar. I know that is possible to do it in segmented control, but I can't figure out how to do it in scope bar.

Comment: Please add some code of what you have achieved, what you expected to achieve and why it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

> Duplicate: This has been answered [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805754/how-to-change-uisearchbar-icon-to-custom-image):

`searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "your image"), forSearchBarIcon: .Search, state: .Normal)`

Comment: the post above changing image in the searchbar, or what i want to change is the image in the scope bar ( segmented control). any way i will use segmented control instead of the scope bar which i can set image for the desired index easly.